# How to make svm object detection ignore complex background?

Tags: image, machine-learning, svm

I'm thinking about a problem. If I have some worm's image with really poor resolution, I can just see thier shape, like the picture

[image]

now I use HOG with SVM to train the data, and use search window to find the worm, the result would be always good in clean background

[image]

sometimes there are some noise but I can always use some filters to clean it, or I can train the noisy backgrounds as negative data in svm

[image]

but life always hard in reality, often some really big objects would enter my search windows and my worm's feature would be disrupted
[image]

i'm considering if I have some ground truth of worm, and hope the svm trainer would ignore the merge near the worm since I don't care if unlabel region(black area of ground truth) is white(in search window) or not[image]

then It would give me the result which have ignored the background

[image]

Is it possible? I search google and find some segementation methods but all of them focus on image pre-processing. Thanks for any key word!

Comment: What kind of search window do you use?

Comment: just a basic rectangle sliding windows from top-left to bottom-right

Comment: You do something like non-max-suppression to merge the sub regions?